# Local field 'email' in class 'Colaborador' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User', but there is no email field in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am a beginner at python and django, I'm using for the first time to collaborate in a college's project and I just run into an error a little odd

Whenever I try to make the migrations of my files, it keeps warning me

"Local field 'email' in class 'Colaborador' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'"

The weird thing is that, there is no local field at Colaborador class

my class at models.py

```
class Colaborador(User):
nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
ddd = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name='DDD')
telefone = models.CharField(max_length=9)
administrador_sistema = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['nome']

def get_absolute_url(self): return reverse('colaborador-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

def __str__(self): return self.nome
```

What could it be? Does someone has some idea?

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of the code in the question. Unless that's the bug?

Comment: If you aren't the sole writer of the code, did `Colaborador` once have an `email` field that's been migrated away? A quick grep might be worthwhile. Although I don't know if that could confuse things, or not.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.